# Simplifying $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{e^{3x} + e^{-3x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you simplify $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{e^{3x} + e^{-3x}}$

This is really confusing to me because there are two $e$'s on top of each other with the same exponent.

My first thought was to make it $-1$ by canceling them out. That doesn't work though.

My second thought was to flip them since they have negative exponents, which is what I would normally do, but I was confused because they both have negative exponents, and I don't know how to deal with exponents in the denominator.

Comment: Is it $$e^{3x}-e^{-3x}$$ or $$e^{3x}-e^{3^x}$$?

Comment: The numerator is the top one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply by $\color{grey}{1=}\dfrac {e^{-3x}}{e^{-3x}}$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What would multiplying by one do?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 Multiplying by $1$ doesn't change anything. Have you simplified the resulting expression?

Comment: Yeah, I got $\frac{0}{2}$

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 You misscomputed something. Given $x\in \mathbb R$, note that $$\begin{align} 
\dfrac{e^{3x} - e^{-3x}}{e^{3x} + e^{-3x}}&=\dfrac {e^{-3x}}{e^{-3x}}\dfrac{e^{3x} - e^{-3^x}}{e^{3x} + e^{-3x}}\\ 
&=\dfrac{e^{-3x+3x}-e^{-3x-3x}}{e^{-3x+3x}+e^{-3x-3x}}\\
&=\dfrac{1-e^{-6x}}{1+e^{-6x}}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{3x} = \infty$ and the limit of the other exponential expressions is zero. By the squeeze theorem you get that the limit is bounded between $\lim_{x \to \infty} (e^{3x} + 1)/e^{3x}$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{3x}/(e^{3x} + 1).$

Comment: Never learned squeeze theorem

Comment: It's something you can almost use without proof because it's intuitively clear: If $L(x) \leq f(x) \leq U(x)$ and $\lim_x L(X) = \lim_x U(x)$ then $f(x)$ has the same limit too.